# Mule: No Receiver registered error during Functional Test case run

Tags: mule

I was trying to develop a Functional Test case for my mule configuration. Here is the code:

```
protected String getConfigResources() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return "src/test/resources/employee-get-functionalTestCase-config.xml";
    }

    @Test
    public void testMessage() throws Exception {
        MuleClient client = muleContext.getClient();
        client.dispatch("vm://in", "70009", null);

        MuleMessage result = client.request("vm://out", 60000);
        Assert.assertNotNull("Response payload was null", result);
        Assert.assertNull(result.getExceptionPayload());
        Assert.assertFalse(result.getPayload() instanceof NullPayload);
```

& here is the context of my XMl file:

```
<spring:beans>
        <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:mule-app.properties"/>
    </spring:beans>
    <flow name="testFlow">
        <vm:inbound-endpoint path="in"/>
        <logger message="in functional-test-config.xml (v4)" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <set-payload value="70010" doc:name="Use fixed employeeId 70010"/>
        <vm:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" path="employee-profile-get" doc:name="VM"/>
        <logger message="after employee-profile-get; payload: #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>

        <vm:outbound-endpoint path="out"/>
    </flow>
```

However when I execute this code, I get the following error:

org.mule.api.transport.NoReceiverForEndpointException: There is no receiver registered on connector "connector.VM.mule.default" for endpointUri vm://employee-profile-get

Where do I register the vm endpoint?

Answer (score 1):

You must have an inbound endpoint for every exchange-pattern="request-response" vm endpoint .

When the application is run in your mule studio you may not get any error(at compile time ) but when the message is passed through the flow you will get an error of the above mentioned sort .

This is because VM is an in-memory queue ,where once you put a message, there should be a receiver  to pick the message thus when not there this error pops and it is only for the exchange-pattern="request-response" because the flow from where you put the message(outbound endpoint with request-response) will wait for a response from the vm endpoint  "employee-profile-get" .

To depict the same error replace the  with a localhost http endpoint and try invoking the http endpoint .

To avoid this create another flow with inbound endpoint as vm with path="employee-profile-get" and return a string using set payload component .Then your test case would work.

Regards,
Naveen Raj